# Search bar not showing in view controller

Tags: swift, uisearchcontroller

I am trying to add a search bar to my view controller programmatically but the issue

I am encountering is that the search bar is not being visible in the view controller, I was wondering how would I display the search bar within the view controller.

```swift
class LocationViewController: UIViewController {

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var resultSearchControlle: UISearchController? = nil

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let locationSearchTable = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(identifier: "LocationSearchTable") as! LocationTableViewController

        resultSearchControlle = UISearchController(searchResultsController: locationSearchTable)

        resultSearchControlle?.searchResultsUpdater = locationSearchTable

        let searchBar = resultSearchControlle!.searchBar

        searchBar.sizeToFit()

        searchBar.placeholder = "Search for a place"

        navigationItem.titleView = resultSearchControlle?.searchBar
        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false

        definesPresentationContext = true

        locationSearchTable.mapView = mapView

    }
```

Comment: iOS 11+?  Try `navigationItem.searchController = resultSearchControlle`

Comment: Yes it is iOS 11+, I did try that to no avail

Comment: you are just adding searchbar ... not controller

Comment: I think your issue might be that you don't have a navigation bar with which to display the search bar.  If you embed your LocationViewController in a Navigation Controller, I think the search bar might appear as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embed the view controller you want the search bar to appear in, inside a Navigation Controller:

Select your LocationViewController in Storyboard, and then in the menu..

Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller

Answer (score 0):

I am using your code and getting this result

```
var resultSearchControlle: UISearchController? = nil
    // MARK: - Constants

    //static let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        resultSearchControlle = UISearchController()
        let searchBar = resultSearchControlle!.searchBar
        searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchBar.placeholder = "Search for a place"
        navigationItem.titleView = resultSearchControlle?.searchBar
        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
        definesPresentationContext = true

      //  locationSearchTable.mapView = mapView

    }
```

[image]